# how to display data in alert Box with splitview in android

Tags: android

```
package com.example.example2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView web1;
    WebView web2;
    Button btn;
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final String str1 = "<html>This first Html data</html>";
        final String str2 = "<br /><br />Read the handouts please for tomorrow.<br /><br /><!--homework help homework"
                + "help help with homework homework assignments elementary school high school middle school"
                + "// --><font color='#60c000' size='4'><strong>Please!</strong></font>"
                + "<img src='http://www.homeworknow.com/hwnow/upload/images/tn_star300.gif'  />";
        web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webfirst);
        web2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.websecond);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.compare);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                web1.loadDataWithBaseURL("", str1, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
                web2.loadDataWithBaseURL("", str2, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");

                // we have display This on Alert view with spliting .

            }

        });

    }

}
```

This is my split view activity  when i click on Button we are able to see data in web view with spliting activity  But i have to do that when i click on Button then string 1 and string 2 should display in Pop window within same activity with splitted data how to split alert or pop view in android  Please help me am unable to do this i have tired much But not getting how iw ill do it

Answer (score 0):

Make your activity to dialog in manifest is the one way

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

by adding the above code in your activity you can see the activity as dialog

**(OR)**

Try to display custom dialog in this way

```
Dialog dialog_help = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog_help.setContentView(R.layout.help_screen);
TextView tv_1 = (TextView) dialog_help.findViewById(R.id.tv_help_1);
tv_1.setText("");
dialog_help.setCancelable(true);
dialog_help.setTitle("   Help   ");
dialog_help.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog_help.show();
dialog_help.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
dialog_help.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: can u please give me ur email id so that i can show u my source code please